# Count of dates "This Month" to appear in a text box in Access Report

Tags: ms-access, report

This seems simple but I haven't been able to find it anywhere. I just want to have a simple text box with a formula that pulls the count of dates for THIS MONTH from a specific field to populate on my Access Report.

Basically just trying to show for this month how many
Construction Starts: _______
Construction Completes: ________

Can any one help me with this?

Thanks,

Charles

Comment: Consider `month(date())`

Comment: Sorry but can you please clarify? I tried entering =month([Milestone_6]) into the control source but that isn't working.   if my date field is Milestone_6 what should i enter in the control source to bring up the count of records this month?

Answer (score 0):

As Gustav provided this code works for producing a simple value counting the number of date fields in THIS MONTH. Just adapt what is in quotes to your table/fields.

=DCount("*","YourTable","[YourDateField] Between DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())+1,0)")

Answer (score -1):

Could be:

```
=DCount("*","YourTable","[YourDateField] Between DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())+1,0)")
```

Comment: Please tell how you "figured it out"?

Comment: I just used your code subbing in my date fields and table where you put "*","My Table", My Date field" and the count works. I didn't think something so seemingly simple would have that long a code string but it does work!

Comment: Great. Then could you please upvote to eliminate the -1 from a distracted downvoter? Maybe even mark as an answer.

Comment: I would but I'm not allowed to as a new user and I have below 15 reputation points.  Unfortunately that's the rule.

Comment: OK, then just mark as answered. You are the only one capable of that.